# Concordion with Maven, using different folder for integration tests

Tags: maven, concordion

I am trying to run integration tests (written in Concordion) using Maven 3.2.5. I have done the following.

1. Created a maven project using quickstart archetype.
2. Put my source code in src/main/java, unit test in src/test/java and integration
   tests in src/spec/java.
3. Used maven-antrun-plugin to put integration test *.class in target/integrationtest-classes
4. Use maven-surefire-plugin to run the unit test cases.
5. Use maven-failsafe-plugin to run the integration test cases.
6. Finally run everything using "mvn clean install"

The problem is, while the unit test cases are running, the integration test cases are not. When I run the integration test cases from Eclipse, by running them as JUnit they run alright. However, when I run them from Maven, somehow only the unit test cases run. Can someone please help.

I am attaching my pom.xml here.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.acme.bundler</groupId>
<artifactId>concordion</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>concordion</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!-- Integration test. -->
    <integrationSourceDirectory>src/spec/java</integrationSourceDirectory>
    <integrationOutputDirectory>target/integrationtest-classes</integrationOutputDirectory>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.concordion</groupId>
        <artifactId>concordion</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Compile and run using jdk 1.7 -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerArguments>
                                <d>${integrationOutputDirectory}</d>
                            </compilerArguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Run the main class of Java. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.acme.bundler.concordion.App</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>foo</argument>
                        <argument>bar</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- The artefacts of integration tests need to move to a different folder 
                than the output of unit tests. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-directory</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo message="Creating Directory ${integrationOutputDirectory}" />
                                <mkdir dir="${integrationOutputDirectory}" />
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <!-- Move the .class of the .java files in integration tests. <mkdir 
                dir="${itest.testOutputDirectory}" /> <move todir="${itest.testOutputDirectory}"> 
                <fileset dir="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"> <include name="**/*.class" 
                /> <present targetdir="${spec.testSourceDirectory}"> <mapper type="glob" 
                from="*.class" to="*.java" /> </present> </fileset> </move> -->




            <!-- Surefire is designed to run the unit tests. If any of the tests 
                break the whole build breaks. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <test>**/*.java</test>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Failsafe is designed to run integration tests. -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testClassesDirectory>${integrationOutputDirectory}</testClassesDirectory>
                    <reportsDirectory>${integrationOutputDirectory}/failsafe-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <test>**/*.java</test>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>

                    <!-- Copy integration tests. -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-sources</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${integrationSourceDirectory}</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-resources</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${integrationSourceDirectory}</directory>
                                    <targetPath>${integrationOutputDirectory}</targetPath>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-empty-directory</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${integrationSourceDirectory}</directory>
                                    <targetPath>${integrationOutputDirectory}</targetPath>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: what maven goal do you use? The surefire and failsafe plugins execute in a different build phase. But mvn install should execute both. mvn test will not: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html- are you sure there are classes for the failsafe plugin to work with? the build-helper plugin has an exclude **/* line (not sure what is does)